# Android Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, android

Recently, I was wondering if it was possible to run Android on a Raspberry Pi and then be able to vnc or use remote desktop apps to access its GUI.

Comment: You're expected to do some research before you ask. Googling for `run Android on a Raspberry Pi` and `Android VNC server` brings in lots of results.

Comment: It's hard to imagine you didn't see similar questions popping up as you were typing your question.

Answer (score 1):

As both Android and Raspberry Pi run on ARM hardware this is totally possible. You can use [RTAndroid](https://rtandroid.embedded.rwth-aachen.de/downloads/raspberry-pi/).

Another alternative [tutorial specific for the Raspberry Pi 3](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html)

And as mentioned, search before posting.